# Magento getCustomerId() in pdf

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

i try to get the customerId in the Shipment PDF.

I tried this code (the output is in the right of any row after // )

```
$order = $shipment->getOrder();

$this->page->drawText($order->getCustomerEmail(), $this->margin_left, $this->y, $this->charset); //outputs the correct email

$this->page->drawText($order->getCustomerName(), $this->margin_left, $this->y, $this->charset); //outputs the correct name

$this->page->drawText($order->getCustomerId(), $this->margin_left, $this->y, $this->charset); //outputs nothing

$this->page->drawText(var_export($order->getCustomerId(), true), $this->margin_left, $this->y, $this->charset); //outputs 'NULL'
```

Did i forget something to draw the correct id of the customer ? My current version is 1.6.2.

Thanks for your solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `customer_id` attribute is only filled when the order was placed by a registered and logged-in user.

For guests the `customer_id` attribute of the order is always `null`. That's why you get no output.

Comment: Thanks dude! Thats it... i searched hours for a solution ... i tried it again with a Customer that is registered and it worked! I thougth the customer which was the "test" customer was already registered ... Thanks a lot!